# How to add basic authentication for Tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am currently trying to serve a model built with Tensorflow's dnn premade estimator with TF serving. I am very happy to see the release of the restful API with Tensorflow Serving 1.8.

However, if we can specify  what will contain the input and the output, I don't see how to manage basic authentication.

Thanks in advance for your advices.
Regards.

Comment: Ok, I don't know, who downvotes my post, but the least he should have done is explain why he did that. The fact is, according to the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest) in the website of tensorflow, we know how to call a specific model via the URL. This is the following code : POST http://host:port/<URI>:<VERB>   with  

URI: /v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}[/versions/${MODEL_VERSION}]
And  VERB: classify|regress|predict.

Comment: However, nowhere in the tutorial, they explain how to add basic authentication. In this tutorial of [tensorflow] (https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic), they told us that we just launch tensorflow_model_server (so a black box) that will use our models. SO I don't see how to add the authentication. So again thank you for your advices, and for the one who downvotes my post, thank you to explain why you did that.

Comment: It is not explain in the doc how to do that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "manage basic authentication"? Can you elaborate

Comment: @user961954, As I did not find a way, I used a flask server which managed the basic authentication and which launch the tensorflow models.

Comment: @tensorflow-support, what i wanted was to add a login password to access my model with Tensorflow serving

Comment: Can you take a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63178778/11530462) from a similar SO thread? Also you can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) as a reference and let us know if it helps in adding authentication to `tensorflow serving`. Thanks!