# Tensorflow Serving authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-run

I'm using tensorflow serving version 2.2 on Docker with the client REST on Google Cloud Run, i would like to create some authentication method to improve the security.

How can I implement TF Serving with authentication ? I don't found references.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run currently doesn’t have builtin support end-user authentication easily. You can use something like [Firebase Auth with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) to authenticate interactive (browser) users.

However, it seems you have a REST API (headless requests). If you want to built authentication/authorization you pretty much have to build something like OAuth (also explained in the same link above).

If you are trying to just authenticate yourself, you can implement HTTP Basic Authentication (username:password, passed in a header).

Answer (score -2):

You can add a authentication by linux firewall......

Comment: Are you talk about iptables ? Tell me more.